# Can you force a NSWindow to load, i.e. before it is presented onscreen?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am all in favor of lazy instantiation of objects only once they are needed, especially with heavy ones like NSWindows. Unfortunately though I am using a WebKit view and need a way to preload a page (which can take up to 10) seconds, so I would like to kick off the view hierarchy initialization as soon as the app launches. I am building a task bar application so no windows are visible at startup.

My first instinct is a quick "hide and show" but there must be a better way to force a window to unarchive itself and call its `awakeFromNib` and `windowDidLoad` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an NSWindowController to manage the window, you can call the window controller's `-window` method to cause it to load the window without showing it. Like so:

```
// Window is not loaded
[windowController window];
// Window is now loaded but not on screen
[windowController showWindow:nil];
// Window is now visible
```

Comment: Animation doens't show up with "[windowController window]".